# create a dictionary/list with two pairs of key : value / item which have iterating forms

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I want to get a dictionary and list like

```
{f1(0):g1(0), f2(0):g2(0),f1(1):g1(1), f2(1):g2(1)}
[f1(0),f2(0),f1(1),f2(1)]
```

where `f1(x), f2(x)` and `g1(x), g2(x)` are some  defined functions.

There are two generating groups `f1(x):g1(x),f2(x):g2(x)` and `for i in range(2)`.

We can define this dictionary by following code

```
new_dict = {f1(x):g1(x) for x in range(2)}
new_dict.update({f2(x):g2(x) for x in range(2)})
```

However list has order and it seems that I have to create such list by for loop.

```
new_list= list()
for i in range(2)
    new_list.append(f1(i))
    new_list.append(f2(i))
```

I wonder whether there is some elegant way like following:

```
{f1(x):g1(x), f2(x):g2(x) for x in range(2)}
[f1(x) , f2(x)  for x in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list of the functions in the comprehension.

```
{f(x): g(x) for x in range(2) for f, g in [(f1, g1), (f2, g2)]}
```

The list could also possibly be a dict, depending on how much you care about ordering (like if a key might get overwritten) But note that Python 3.7 dicts are now specified to remember the insertion order (and there's always `OrderedDict`)

```
new_dict = {f(x): g(x) for x in range(2) for f, g in {f1:g1, f2:g2}.items()}
```

You can convert the keys to a list like

```
new_list = [*new_dict]
```

This will have the same insertion order, but the dict cannot contain duplicate keys, so the list made from it won't either. This may or may not be what you want.

If you do want to keep duplicates, make a list of pairs first, and then use that to make the dict and list.

```
pairs = [(f(x), g(x)) for x in range(2) for f, g in [(f1, g1), (f2, g2)]]
new_dict = dict(pairs)
new_list = [f for f, _ in pairs]
```

If you're still using an old version of Python, note that you can also make an `OrderedDict` from pairs like this,

```
from collections import OrderedDict

new_dict = OrderedDict((f(x), g(x)) for x in range(2) for f, g in [(f1, g1), (f2, g2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder whether there is some elegant way like following:
>
> ```
> {f1(x):g1(x), f2(x):g2(x) for x in range(2)}
> [f1(x) , f2(x)  for x in range(2)]
> ```

You can have a varying number of outputs each loop by using chain.

```
from itertools import chain

[*chain.from_iterable([f1(x), f2(x)] for x in range(2))]
dict(*chain.from_iterable([(f1(x), g1(x)), (f2(x), g2(x))] for x in range(2)))
```

You can also do the chaining yourself, but it takes more loops.

```
[f for fs in ((f1(x), f2(x)) for x in range(2)) for f in fs]
```